# Convert matlab symbol to array of products

Tags: matlab, split, symbolic-math, factoring

Can I convert a symbol that is a product of products into an array of products?

I tried to do something like this:

```
syms A B C D;
D = A*B*C;
factor(D);
```

but it doesn't factor it out (mostly because that isn't what factor is designed to do).

```
ans =
A*B*C
```

I need it to work if A B or C is replaced with any arbitrarily complicated parenthesized function, and it would be nice to do it without knowing what variables are in the function.

For example (all variables are symbolic):

```
D = x*(x-1)*(cos(z) + n);
factoring_function(D);
```

should be: 
`[x, x-1, (cos(z) + n)]`

It seems like a string parsing problem, but I'm not confident that I can convert back to symbolic variables afterwards (also, string parsing in matlab sounds really tedious).

Thank you!

Comment: What `version` of Matlab are you using? In R2014b, `factor(A*B*C)` returns `[ A, B, C ]`. The other example works fine too. Or are trying to write your own version for an assignment?

Comment: I'm in 2013b. It's not for an assignment, rather a research project. I actually found a function that does the job called 'children'. I'm still testing it to make sure it doesn't have any corner cases (I don't want it to split by sums, only products)

Comment: I can't test if there's a difference between versions, but I wouldn't be surprised if there was. Perhaps you might also try using the second argument for `sym/factor`. You might also find `symvar` helpful. Feel free to answer your own question if you find a solution – just specify which Matlab `version` you're using.

Comment: Excellent. I will post once I have some code that works. In the meantime, upvotes for telling me about `symvar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`regexp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) on the string to split based on `*`:

```
>> str = 'x*(x-1)*(cos(z) + n)';
>> factors_str = regexp(str, '\*', 'split')
factors_str = 
    'x'    '(x-1)'    '(cos(z) + n)'
```

The result `factor_str` is a cell array of strings. To convert to a cell array of `sym` objects, use

```
N = numel(factors_str);
factors = cell(1,N); %// each cell will hold a sym factor
for n = 1:N
    factors{n} = sym(factors_str{n});
end
```

Comment: Not what I ended up doing, but probably a more appropriate answer for those who come here looking for matlab code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing the code to do this in python using sympy. I think I'm going to port the matlab code over to python because it is a more preferred language for me. I'm not claiming this is fast, but it serves my purposes.

```
# Factors a sum of products function that is first order with respect to all symbolic variables
# into a reduced form using products of sums whenever possible.
# @params orig_exp     A symbolic expression to be simplified
# @params depth        Used to control indenting for printing
# @params verbose      Whether to print or not
def factored(orig_exp, depth = 0, verbose = False):
  # Prevents sympy from doing any additional factoring
  exp = expand(orig_exp)
  if verbose: tabs = '\t'*depth
  terms = []

  # Break up the added terms
  while(exp != 0):
    my_atoms = symvar(exp)
    if verbose: 
      print tabs,"The expression is",exp
      print tabs,my_atoms, len(my_atoms)

    # There is nothing to sort out, only one term left
    if len(my_atoms) <= 1:
      terms.append((exp, 1))
      break

    (c,v) = collect_terms(exp, my_atoms[0])
    # Makes sure it doesn't factor anything extra out
    exp = expand(c[1])
    if verbose: 
      print tabs, "Collecting", my_atoms[0], "terms."
      print tabs,'Seperated terms with ',v[0], ',  (',c[0],')'

    # Factor the leftovers and recombine
    c[0] = factored(c[0], depth + 1)
    terms.append((v[0], c[0]))


  # Combines trivial terms whenever possible
  i=0
  def termParser(thing): return str(thing[1])
  terms = sorted(terms, key = termParser) 

  while i<len(terms)-1:
    if equals(terms[i][1], terms[i+1][1]):
      terms[i] = (terms[i][0]+terms[i+1][0], terms[i][1])
      del terms[i+1]
    else:
      i += 1

  recombine = sum([terms[i][0]*terms[i][1] for i in range(len(terms))])
  return simplify(recombine, ratio = 1)
```